# What is the value of the polytropic constant $K$ for a neutron Star?

Tags: thermodynamics, astrophysics, neutron-stars

I need to solve the TOV-Equations for a polytropic EOS, but I don't know what value I'm supposed to use for the polytropic constant $K$ in the EOS and also what the unit for $K$ is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A polytropic equation of state would be something like $P = K\rho^{\alpha}$.

The units of $K$ are of course entirely dependent on what you choose the polytropic exponent $\alpha$ to be. A value of $\alpha \sim 2-3$ is probably appropriate for a neutron star.

The value of $K$ could be set by matching the polytropic equation of state onto a known pressure, density pair $(P_0, \rho_0)$ calculated using a more certain equation of state at lower densities (e.g. the Harrison-Wheeler equation of state).
Thus at the "join", $P_0 = K\rho_0^{\alpha}$, which defines the value of $K$.

Comment: For $\gamma (\alpha) \approx 2$ (adiabatic index), $K \sim \mathrm{N \cdot m^4/kg^2}$.  For a neutron star, what reasonable value should we get for $K$?